# Blocking DNS amplification attacks on ipv6 with iptables

Tags: networking, dns, iptables, ipv6, denial-of-service

I'm running a small Pi-Hole DNS server on my VPS, and I have the following iptables rules enabled to stop the DNS ANY amplification attack:

```
*raw
-A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -m string --from 40 --algo bm --hex-string "|0000FF0001|" -m recent --name dnsanyquery --rcheck --seconds 60 --hitcount 1 -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 53 -m string --from 52 --algo bm --hex-string "|0000FF0001|" -m recent --name dnsanyquery --rcheck --seconds 60 --hitcount 1 -j DROP
COMMIT
```

(source: https://freek.ws/2017/03/18/blocking-dns-amplification-attacks-using-iptables/)

These two rules work great on ipv4 (I have been under constant attack for weeks now, but all requests are getting blocked), but I've just realized that I don't have an ipv6 equivalent for them, and I don't know if the hex string is compatible, or what the offset would be. I haven't been targeted on ipv6 yet, but I'd rather be ready in advance - especially since my ipv6 address has picked up a couple of port scanners already.

What are the ipv6 equivalent rules to block DNS ANY requests?

Answer (score 0):

The rule for IPv6 should be the same except for the `--from` argument value.

Since the IP and UDP headers are larger in IPv6 (due to the longer addresses), the DNS section starts later.

According to the [UDP wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#IPv6_pseudo_header), the DNS section offset is 48 bytes, so for UDP you should use `--from 48` in your iptables rules.

```
-A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -m string --from 48 --algo bm --hex-string "|0000FF0001|" -m recent --name dnsanyquery --rcheck --seconds 60 --hitcount 1 -j DROP
```

For TCP you should check for a similar offset, but I'm not sure the same kind of rule applies. There are many more packets going back and forth in TCP that aren't DNS, for example the 3-way handshake sequence would not match this rule, which means the remote host would still establish a connection but would not be able to make any DNS ANY query through it.